# Scala to HBASE- ZooKeeperRegistry: ClusterId read in ZooKeeper is null

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am using the following code to connect to my HBASE which is running on local sandbox.

I am using the following code, zookeeper and hbase master are running finw. I can scan the HBASE table by going to the HBASE Shell. Not sure whats going wrong here?:

```
object HBaseWrite {
       def main(args: Array[String]) {
         System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "c://hadoop");
         val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HBaseWrite").setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts","true").set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
         val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
         val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
         val outputTable = "TABLE1"

         System.setProperty("user.name", "hdfs")
         System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "hdfs")
         conf.set("hbase.master", "localhost:60000")
         conf.setInt("timeout", 120000)
         conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.163.129/sandbox.hortonworks.com")
         conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure")
         conf.setInt("hbase.client.scanner.caching", 10000)
         sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result]))
         val jobConfig: JobConf = new JobConf(conf,this.getClass)
         jobConfig.setOutputFormat(classOf[TableOutputFormat])
         jobConfig.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE,outputTable)
         val x = 12
         val y = 15
         val z = 25
         var newarray = Array(x,y,z)
         val newrddtohbase = sc.parallelize(newarray)
         val convertFunc = convert _
         new PairRDDFunctions(newrddtohbase.map(convertFunc)).saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConfig)
         sc.stop()
       }
       def convert(a:Int) : Tuple2[ImmutableBytesWritable,Put] = {
              val p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(a))
              p.add(Bytes.toBytes("columnfamily"),
              Bytes.toBytes("col_1"), Bytes.toBytes(a))
              new Tuple2[ImmutableBytesWritable,Put](new ImmutableBytesWritable(a.toString.getBytes()), p);
         }
    }
```

and get the following error:

```
   ZooKeeperRegistry: ClusterId read in ZooKeeper is null
    17/03/21 20:13:37 INFO ZooKeeperRegistry: ClusterId read in ZooKeeper is null
    17/03/21 20:13:37 INFO ZooKeeperRegistry: ClusterId read in ZooKeeper is null
    17/03/21 20:13:37 INFO ZooKeeperRegistry: ClusterId read in ZooKeeper is null
    17/03/21 20:13:37 INFO SparkHadoopMapRedUtil: No need to commit output of task because needsTaskCommit=false: attempt_201703212013_0000_m_000000_0
    17/03/21 20:13:37 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 874 bytes result sent to driver
    17/03/21 20:13:37 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 816 ms on localhost (1/4)
    17/03/21 20:13:37 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3)
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:208)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientSmallReversedScanner.loadCache(ClientSmallReversedScanner.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientSmallReversedScanner.next(ClientSmallReversedScanner.java:185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1249)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submit(AsyncProcess.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submit(AsyncProcess.java:321)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.backgroundFlushCommits(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.close(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.close(TableOutputFormat.java:66)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.close(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$8.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1211)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1366)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1211)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1190)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.getMetaReplicaNodes(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:395)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:553)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getMetaRegionLocation(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1152)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:151)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
        ... 20 more
    17/03/21 20:13:37 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2)
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:208)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientSmallReversedScanner.loadCache(ClientSmallReversedScanner.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientSmallReversedScanner.next(ClientSmallReversedScanner.java:185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1249)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submit(AsyncProcess.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submit(AsyncProcess.java:321)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.backgroundFlushCommits(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.close(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.close(TableOutputFormat.java:66)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.close(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$8.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1211)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1366)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1211)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1190)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.getMetaReplicaNodes(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:395)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:553)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getMetaRegionLocation(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1152)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:151)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
        ... 20 more
    17/03/21 20:13:37 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:208)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientSmallReversedScanner.loadCache(ClientSmallReversedScanner.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientSmallReversedScanner.next(ClientSmallReversedScanner.java:185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1249)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submit(AsyncProcess.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submit(AsyncProcess.java:321)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.backgroundFlushCommits(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.close(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.close(TableOutputFormat.java:66)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.close(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$8.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1211)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1366)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1211)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1190)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.getMetaReplicaNodes(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:395)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:553)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getMetaRegionLocation(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1152)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:151)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
        ... 20 more
    17/03/21 20:13:37 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, localhost): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:208)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientSmallReversedScanner.loadCache(ClientSmallReversedScanner.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientSmallReversedScanner.next(ClientSmallReversedScanner.java:185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1249)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submit(AsyncProcess.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submit(AsyncProcess.java:321)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.backgroundFlushCommits(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.close(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.close(TableOutputFormat.java:66)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.close(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$8.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1211)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1366)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1211)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1190)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.getMetaReplicaNodes(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:395)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:553)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getMetaRegionLocation(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1152)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:151)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
        ... 20 more

Please help, I am stuck on this bit. HBASE Master and Zookeeper are running fine.
```